# AJAX Rounded Corners extender not getting displayed in email in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, email, .net-3.5, html-email

I have displayed the below HTML source in page and mailed the same. The Rounded Corners extender present in the HTML is not displayed in the email that I sent.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" BackColor="#F9F9F9" Width="740px" runat="server">

                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; color: Black; font-weight: bold;">
                                Name:</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" Style="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: normal;
                                font-size: 11px; color: Black; margin-left: 0px;" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; color: Black; font-weight: bold;">
                                Address:</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" Style="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: normal;
                                font-size: 11px; color: Black; margin-left: 0px;" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>    <!-- Extraneous? -->
        </tr>        <!-- Extraneous? -->
    </table>         <!-- Extraneous? -->
</asp:Panel>
   <cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" Corners="All" TargetControlID="pnlDetails"
    Radius="6" BorderColor="#D5DCDF" runat="server">
</cc1:RoundedCornersExtender>
```

The entire HTML is displayed perfectly in the email except that the rounded corners alone does not appear. If I save the email's HTML source as HTML page and view in browser, the rounded corners is getting displayed perfectly. The panel and rounded corners are getting converted to div's. The following is the source of rounded corners extender present in email (when saved as HTML I got this code):

```
<DIV style='BORDER-LEFT: #d5dcdf 1px solid;
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; HEIGHT: 1px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; OVERFLOW: hidden; 
MARGIN-RIGHT: -2px; BORDER-RIGHT: #d5dcdf 1px solid' __roundedDiv='true'></DIV>  
<DIV style='BORDER-LEFT: #d5dcdf 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; HEIGHT: 1px; 
MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; OVERFLOW: hidden; MARGIN-RIGHT: -2px; BORDER-RIGHT: #d5dcdf 1px solid' 
__roundedDiv='true'></DIV>  <DIV style='BORDER-LEFT: #d5dcdf 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; 
HEIGHT: 1px; MARGIN-LEFT: 1px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; OVERFLOW: hidden; MARGIN-RIGHT: -1px; 
BORDER-RIGHT: #d5dcdf 1px solid' __roundedDiv='true'></DIV>  
<DIV style='BORDER-LEFT: #d5dcdf 1px solid; 
BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent; HEIGHT: 1px; MARGIN-LEFT: 2px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; OVERFLOW: hidden; 
MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: #d5dcdf 1px solid' __roundedDiv='true'></DIV>
```

It is normal HTML except the property __roundedDiv='true' is different from normal HTML code!

For top left, top right, top and bottom part of rounded corner extender, a separate div is created with borders. But the borders are not getting displayed in email!

Please guide me to display the rounded corners in email.

Comment: webpages and emails isnt the same thing email providers provide the most basic functionality of html, you should be clad that even half of that is working

Comment: I viewed the email in MS Outlook only still the rounded corners are not getting displayed. Do you mean that AJAX rounded corners extender cannot be displayed in email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No AJAX and no ASP.Net in email. All you can use it HTML, tables, images, and inline CSS.

For rounded corners, you will need to create an image and position it with a table.

Comment: Ok but while mailing that HTML content to users, I have to add that rounded corner image also as linked resource to that email! This will increase mail size which is not desirable since we already embed four other images in that email.

Comment: I'm just explaining the technical limitations.